# ngOnDestroy not fired after button click in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angular, typescript

HTML..........

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit"

                          value="submit"
                          class="btn btn-secondary btn-float">Upload</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

TS file.........

```
export class testComponent implements  OnDestroy {

ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("Fired ngOnDestroy");
  }

onClickSubmit() {

      this.subscription = this.service
        .create(test, url)
        .subscribe(
              res => {

                console.log('HTTP response', res)
              },
              err => {

                console.log("Error", err)
              },
              () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
        );

  }
  }
```

I am trying to call service on button click after that my ngondestroy() not firing i clueless why it is not working

Comment: ngOnDestroy will be triggered on the destroy of your component. Please check angular lifecycle hooks.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnDestroy` is called by the framework when a component is removed from the DOM.

There is nothing in your example to suggest that the button click *should* trigger a destroy.

If I have the following component, `ngOnDestroy` will be called in the child component when the button is clicked.

```html
<child *ngIf="!deleted"></child>
<button (click)="deleted = true">Trigger destroy in child</button>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxvj1n